# como validar el click de un botón después de 1 segundo con jquery

Tags: jquery, botón

Quiero confirmar el click de un botón, el usuario debe dejar presionado el botón 1 segundo para generar el submit con jquery.

Por ejemplo cuando pulsan aquí:

```html
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"></script>
    <button id="pulsador">Pulsa 1 segundo</button>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta fue cerrada por falta de un Código mínimo y verificable. Siempre se necesita demostrar lo que has intentado o investigado, eso nos indica tu esfuerzo por tratar de resolver tu problema, de lo contrario se puede mal interpretar. Te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask]

Answer (score 2):

Ejecuta éste código:

```js
var tiempo;
$('#pulsador').on("mousedown",function(){
    tiempo = setTimeout(function(){
        alert("Funciona!");
    },1000);
}).on("mouseup mouseleave",function(){
    clearTimeout(tiempo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"></script>
<button id="pulsador">Pulsa 1 segundo</button>
```

### Explicación

Mediante jquery interceptamos el evento `mousedown` del ratón sobre el elemento con id `pulsador`, que es el botón.

A la variable `tiempo`, que nos hara de contador de tiempo, le asignamos la función `setTimeout()` de 1 segundo

Si se cumple el segundo entonces lanzamos un aviso (*alert*) de que ya se ha cumplido. En tu caso querrás enviar un `submit` supongo o una petición ajax.

En caso contrario la variable `tiempo` vuelve a inicializarse en 0.

Comment: Muchas gracias Masterguru

Comment: @RicardoR Si consideras que esta respuesta sirve para solucionar tu pregunta puedes marcarla como respuesta aceptada, asi otros tambien lo veran. En el siguiente enlace encontrarás más información al respecto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: La pregunta fue cerrada debido a que no aclara cual es el problema concreto que tiene y tampoco muestra el código con el que trabaja, prácticamente pide que le hagan el código, puede que la intención no sea esa pero para eso existen los comentarios, donde se puede pedir que agregue cosas que faltan. Lastimosamente ninguno de los votantes de cierre dejó un comentario.

Comment: Igualmente votaré por dejar cerrada la pregunta por falta de un ejemplo mínimo y verificable del problema.

Comment: Si, bueno, cuando expresé mi queja llevaba aqui muy pocos dias y aun no sabia todo eso. Gracias por la explicación igualmente.

Comment: @Christian Lo que me ocurrió tambien en ese momento es que me animé  ha hacerlo debido a que mi nivel de javascript era cero patatero y despues de elaborar la respuesta (tambien para mi mismo) me supo mal que no sirviera para la comunidad, pero ahora lo entiendo y no es problema.

Comment: Ho! bueno, las colas de revisión son extensas y aveces se tarde un poco en evaluar publicaciones. Igual tu respuesta fue bien recibida y siempre puedes editar la pregunta (mientras no vaya en contra de la intención del autor o la acomodes para que concuerde con tu respuesta). Lo mejor siempre es guiar al usuario mediante comentarios :D